# How do you play Civilization 4 by E-Mail?

Tags: civilization-4

Does anyone know if there is a mod or anything to play Civilization 4 over email?  Like if my friend makes a turn, I get sent an email that its my turn and I can log on make my turn or couple of turns and then next player goes.

I know there is a hot seat option which is very useful, but my friends and I want to play games but its hard for us to meet at the same time online.

Comment: I don't have Civ 4, but there is supposedly a "PBEM" (Play By E-Mail) option under multiplayer.  For Civ V, [see this question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/8111/how-do-you-play-civilization-v-by-e-mail).

Comment: Play Hotseat, enter in SMTP settings iirc. It can be done, but I forgot the procedure. I'll check and write an answer later today.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This question was [answered quite well on the CivFanatics Forum by DogBoy](http://forums.civfanatics.com/showpost.php?p=4937605&postcount=2):

> 1. Start game. Click multiplayer, click PBEM, click New game.
> 2. Type in a game name at the top left corner. Call it whatever you like. The game will automatically use this name for all saved games.
>      Type in an admin password in the top right corner. Let's pretend you
>      called the game "friend".
> 3. The first line of players should be called "administrator". Click on the little computer to the left of that name. Now you can fill in
>      all your information. Give yourself a name, blah blah blah, type in
>      your e-mail, your password, and your SMTP information. The e-mail is
>      there because the game knows to send you the game when his turn is
>      over with. It's a neat little feature. The SMTP is there so when you
>      hit end turn, the game will automatically send the game to your friend
>      through your e-mail without you having to e-mail it to him manually. I
>      personally don't use this feature but some people do.
> 4. The next line should be called "player". Click on the little computer to the left of that name. Now fill in all your friend's
>      information. If you don't know his SMTP and his password then no
>      problem, he can fill that out on his turn by hitting the escape key,
>      then clicking on "your information". Let's call your friend Dave.
> 5. The next line should be called "player". This is where you can either put some AI players in the game or close them all to make it a
>      two player game.
> 6. To the right of both your names is the word "random". This is where you choose your civ and leader, as well as your friend's civ and
>      leader. You can also go random.
> 7. At the bottom of the page is where you customize the game. I'm sure you know what settings you want.
> 8. Now you click the bottom right button called "launch". The game is now started!
> 9. When you are done with your turn hit the little flashing red light near your minimap to signify you are done with the turn. If you
>      entered your SMTP information and your friend's e-mail, then game will
>      ask you if you want to e-mail it to him. If you do, then hit yes. Your
>      friend now has the e-mail in his inbox. If you hit no, then exit to
>      desktop.
> 10. Go to your civ4 folder. Mine is called: c:/programfiles/Firaxis Games/Sid Meir's Civilization 4/_civ4saves/pbem. In there you will
>       find a brand new folder called "friend". Remember, that's what we
>       called this game. In that folder is a file called
>       friend_BC_4000_to_Dave. Simply e-mail him that game.
> 11. The first time your friend gets the save he will not have a a folder is his save folder called "friend". He will want to double
>       click the file from his e-mail and the game will launch. After he is
>       done with his turn and he hits end turn, the game will generate the
>       "friend" folder in his save folder. He entered his SMTP info then he
>       can send the file to you from the game. If he didn't enter his SMTP
>       info, he can find the save in his new folder. He can e-mail the save
>       to you from there.
> 12. It helps to make a shortcut to the friend folder and put it on your desktop. That's what I do.

Comment: Your post is very useful, but no sure what SMTP means, and how you get the info?

Comment: @lizawiza Depends on your email provider. You need to get the SMTP server address. Contact them for help.