# Can I play hotseat with mods?

Tags: civilization-5, mods

Maybe there is a hack or something that enables mods in the hotseat mode? I want to play with a friend but we want to use mods.

Answer (score 6):

Yes you can, there is a mod in Steam Workshop which enables the using of mods in Hotseat Mode:

[Custom Advanced Setup Screen](http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=75500984)