# Is there any way to play a custom map in multiplayer?

Tags: civilization-5, mods

Civilization 5's multiplayer does not support any form of modding aside from changing the `.lua` scripts associated with existing multiplayer map options. They consider pre-generated maps 'modding' in this case.

The fact that custom maps are not allowed in multiplayer does not make any sense to me because it does not modify the game in any way, shape, or form. It simply means loading a pre-generated map instead of generating a random one.

There has to be a way to load a custom map for a multiplayer game. It just seems too simple to not be possible. I understand that [it is possible to play with mods/custom maps in hotseat mode](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/65285/can-i-play-hotseat-with-mods), but I am not interested in hotseat as I would like to play a fluid game online with friends.

**Does anyone know if this is at all possible? I'm entirely prepared to work a little to load a custom map in multiplayer if it is at all possible.**

Comment: For a little back story: I used to play WoW back before any of the expansions. I recently reconnected with and started playing other games with an old friend who I met playing WoW years and years ago. There is an Azeroth map that I'd love to play with them, if only it is possible:
http://forums.civfanatics.com/showpost.php?p=9751466&postcount=5 It may have just been a game, but I have some good memories playing it with friends nearly a decade ago!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The patch for 7/2/2013 to Civilization 5 is adding the ability to play custom maps in multiplayer games:

> - Added ability to play custom maps in multiplayer. Host and all players must place custom maps in the main games "maps" directory to be usable.

Source: [2kGames Forum](http://forums.2kgames.com/showthread.php?247316-New-patch-en-route)