# Can you play a map on Multiplayer?

Tags: civilization-5

I Looked at a post here: [Is there any way to play a custom map in multiplayer?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/106098/is-there-any-way-to-play-a-custom-map-in-multiplayer)
but the link does not work for me anymore. Can someone provide a new link or just say how it is done please? Thank You.

Comment: Link worked for me.  Mentioned this post: http://steamcommunity.com/app/8930/discussions/0/828935361271238590/

Comment: Sorry, Elmarkador, the proper course of action is to update the existing post, not make a new one.  Once you get some rep, you can post comments on questions and/or visit [chat].