# How do you play multiplayer in Civilization V?

Tags: civilization-5

In the game there is a tab for multiplayer and after that, the "Internet" option.

When I clicked it, only one game was there and it was only two people. So how do you connect and play multiplayer?

Comment: You could also wait for correspondence Civ 5 to come out.
[Link]


: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/8111/how-do-you-play-civilization-v-by-e-mail

Answer (score 1):

Games that have already started do not show up in this list, only those that are in the lobby state. As games are very long, it's normal for only a few games to ever be listed.

You have two options at this point, refresh the screen until a new game appears that you want to join, or host a game yourself and wait for others to join it.