# How do I create a Pitboss game?

Tags: civilization-5

A [recent patch](http://forums.2kgames.com/showthread.php?89117-Patch-Notes&p=3104141#post3104141) for Civilization V introduced the Pitboss mode. How do I create a Pitboss-using game? How do I join one?

I browsed around in the settings and found a place to configure how the Pitboss game sends "it's your turn" messages, but couldn't actually find a way to start such a game.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When you're setting up a Multiplayer game, there's an option for Pitboss under the Advanced Game Options.

[image: Screenshot of mutiplayer game setup dialogue]

Comment: Thanks @SevenSidedDie. I didn't have the ability yet to embed the image. :)

Comment: Also note that you need to go to multiplayer, then host game to get these advanced options. And it looks like everyone needs to be online when you first start the game.