# Convert a multiplayer game to Pitboss format?

Tags: civilization-5

I started a game with a few friends in the normal multiplayer format, but it may be hard to get us all together again to finish it later.  The game is saved locally on my computer.  Is it possible to convert it to a Pitboss-format game so that we can play asynchronously?

Comment: related: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/122937/how-do-i-create-a-pitboss-game

Answer (score 1):

You can convert a game into Pitboss format!

When you go to set up a Pitboss game, look at the bottom of the screen for a **Load Game** button. You can then select a local or steam save, including games launched in another format. In order to launch the new pitboss game, you will need all players to connect to the **Staging Room**. They must all be connected **before** clicking launch game.

Note: This was tested with BNW & G&K expansions installed, there may be differences for vanilla Civ 5

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: When I have some time, I will test your method;  if it works, I will accept and upvote this answer.  I'm glad someone finally answered!

Answer (score 0):

I made a simple web app that will let you change the game parameters of a save file, including the pitboss setting: [Civilization V save editor](https://bmaupin.github.io/civ5save-editor/)

Just open your save file in the app and check *Pitboss*. Then download the new save file with the changes and open it in the game.