# Civilization VI - Asynchronous Multiplayer (aka PitBoss)

Tags: civilization-6

Does Civ VI has support for asynchronous multiplayer? I.E., can a server be set up that allows players to take turns when they want, rather than everyone needing to be logged in at the same time?

Comment: Does PBEM (play by email) count as asynchronous multiplayer for your purposes?

Comment: I'd like to be able for multiple people to submit turns at their leisure, passing around an email for more than 2 people sounds tough.

Comment: Once upon a time it was all we had (i.e., Civ 2-3) and it was sufficient :)  But understood, thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 3):

Right now nothing was said about pitboss mode in civ6.

Comment: To @camelCase and the other flaggers/downvoters: This *is* an answer, [since pitboss mode is an async game](https://www.reddit.com/r/civ/comments/2x3tdu/what_exactly_is_pitboss_mode_and_will_it_make/). Please, refrain from downvoting and flagging if you don't undertand the answer, because it's pretty clear the flaggers and downvoters here don't know what pitboss mode is.

Comment: @Wipqozn As answers go, this one is incredibly poor.  You should not be stifling how people vote by leaving such comments.  That's nowhere near what a mod's job is.  Decline flags, yes.  Tell people they don't understand the answer and shouldn't downvote, no.

Comment: @Frank The answer is exactly what it should be. "Does this feature exist?" "No". What more is there to say?

Comment: @Wipqozn What proof is shown?  What legitimacy is offered to help underscore the statement? Nothing at all.  You're creating a chilling effect by telling people not to vote, and that *will* stifle future voting.  That's not your job as a moderator.  I have no issue with you telling people that you consider it an answer and will decline NAA flags on that basis.  This is strictly with you telling people not to downvote.  Even if this counts as an answer, it's a very poor one, and can be downvoted on that alone.

Comment: @Frank Folks shouldn't be downvoting or flagging an answer because they don't know what "pitboss mode" means. Full stop. As a moderator, it *is* my job to point that out. It's an abuse of downvotes. If you downvoted because you think the answer should provide some evidence of a feature  not existing then what I said doesn't apply to you. Finally, this is very clearly an answer, because it's an attempt to answer the question. Lack of proof doesn't suddenly make it not an answer.

Comment: @Wipqozn I disagree.  If people are downvoting because they don't understand what pitboss mode is, then perhaps that's because *the answer doesn't explain it*.  Which is literally what downvoting is *for*!  No, they shouldn't be flagging, I agree with that.  But an answer being downvoted because someone doesn't understand it is kinda one of the main reasons to do it.  It's not an abuse in any sense.

Comment: I can't find appropiate meta topic, but I do remember reading that we do not in fact want to tell people why and when to downvote (except for a few basic safeguards like against serial downvote). Community matters, not individuals. In that spirit I upvoted the answer (since, if correct, there is literally nothing more to say), agree with leaving a message that flagging it is inappropiate, and disagree with "refrain from downvoting" part.

Comment: @Frank If it was some term that didn't appear in the games at all I'd be more inclined to agree, but Pitboss mode is what the game mode is actually called in game, as seen [here](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/122937/how-do-i-create-a-pitboss-game).

Comment: @Wipqozn I can understand your viewpoint, I just disagree with what I see as a chilling effect on voting.  To that end, I think we're going to have to agree to disagree.

Comment: @Wipqozn - This answer appeared in the low quality queue.  It is low quality, because it is basically in the form of a comment.  My reason is nothing to do with knowing pitboss mode.  I voted for deletion because I couldn't edit away my problems with the answer (e.g. "nothing was said"??).  I can't answer for others who VTC or downvoted etc.  http://gaming.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/208511

Comment: @camelCase It's in the form of an answer. The question is "Is this a thing that exists?", to which the answer is "No".

Comment: @camelCase - i believe, that it is not that easy to actually show any good proof that pitboss do not exist nor was mentioned by Firaxis. What kind of prove you do actually expect? Link to some forums with the same stament? "about:blank" page with statements of developers about pitboss in civ 6? It is easier to provide proofs about something that do exist...